# How to avoid rows with null values to overwrite existing ones in phoenix when saving dataframe from spark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-phoenix

I'm creating a spark job (in scala). Its role is to read in a mysql table several rows with a json column containing columns/values to update in a apache phoenix system. My json column is used to create as many columns in the dataframe as there are keys in the json (simple key values json)

Json columns match with my target table in phoenix. However,some columns in the json might be missing for some rows. In this case, i end up with some null values for some fields in my dataframe.

I would like to save (upsert) my dataframe to my phoenix table  to ignore these null values and only update columns that have a value. Currently, it is overwriting values in phoenix target table with NULL if the  column does not exist in my json string.

I looked in detail the "save mode" of dataframe save method, but no mode is good for me (append/overwrite/ignore..)

example data in the dataframe (json_tags_with_id value)

```
{"id":3,"app_version":"test_versionb","ad_id":"test"}                      {"id":500012326,"sec_id":"a9d2851dcfb1c6d3","app_version":"test_version"}
```

```
val schematest3 = new StructType().add($"id".int).add($"sec_id".string).add($"app_version".string).add($"ad_id".string);

val df2=dataFrame.withColumn("json_tags_with_id", from_json(col("json_tags_with_id"), schematest3)).select(col("analytique_date"),col("json_tags_with_id.*"));

df2.write.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark").mode("overwrite").option("batchsize",10000).option("table", "\"my_target_table\"").option("zkUrl", "jdbc:phoenix...").save()
```

Comment: I think this would be something that you would want to handle in Spark, I don't think there really is a way to do that in Phoenix. To understand correctly, you want to filter columns which are null or rows which are null?

Comment: I want to prevent some columns having null values in my dataframe to update the phoenix database with null values, i would prefer that these columns are just ignored from the update